# Smallest collection of subsets that generate a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Assume X is a given set and B is a sigma algebra in X. Does there exist a smallest generating collection S of subsets of X that generate B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in the sense of smallest *cardinality* (that is a simple consequnce of the well-orderedness of cardinals).

No, in the sense of *minimal wrt to inclusion*, in most interesting cases, like the Borel sets of standard spaces.

Comment: Could you explain more your first point please.

Comment: @HAT The set of cardinalities of subsets of $B$ that generate $B$ is non-empty ($|B|$ is in it, trivially) so has a minimum.