# Are All Generating Sets for the Borel Algebra Uncountable?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

A related question asks is there a smallest set that generates a given $\sigma$-algebra:

[Smallest collection of subsets that generate a sigma algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229949/smallest-collection-of-subsets-that-generate-a-sigma-algebra)

The [only existing answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3229998/252983) to that (at the time of writing this) says that there must be a smallest cardinality for any generating set of any $\sigma$-algebra, by the well-orderedness of cardinals.

Focusing on the Borel sigma algebra over the Reals, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, the above implies that there's a smallest such cardinality of a set that generates this algebra. But is that smallest cardinality uncountable? I believe this is formally what I'm asking:

$$|\mathbb{N}| \notin \{|S| \mid S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \wedge \sigma(S) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$$

My intuition says yes. If there was a countable set generating the Borel algebra it would seem weird... but I'm not sure...

Comment: The word "any" is ambiguous, and your title can be read as "Is there some generating set which is uncountable"? It is better, when possible, to use "all" or "every" and"some" to clarify the quantifier. It is also good to be positive: you can ask, "is there a countable generating set", for example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK agreed on the ambiguity of quantifiers. I think I almost agree with you on the positivity thing- I usually enforce this rule in the field of computer programming when I do code reviews - but at the same time, my original mental state was that "all generating sets are uncountable" so I think that more correctly captures the essence of my thinking at the time of asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open intervals $(a,b)$ with $a$ and $b$ rational form a countable class generating the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$.